# Create a Modal Dialog box containing a form using struts2

Tags: struts2, struts, modal-dialog

In my application I have a part of form which should allow details of a n number of persons.
i.e,

Field1 
Field2
field3

now a button 
Details of persons

on button click it open a modal dialog box containg a form with 3 fields about person.When I click save.
the details of persons sections should update...This should repeat on every button click..
I also need validations for fields on modal dialog box.

Th data entered for field1,2,3 should remain same during the process..

How to do this in struts2.I am facing a lot of problems can some one help me with a simple example..

Regards,
Lalitha

One more problem is to have a date picker on modal dialog box..

Answer (score 1):

a modal dialog is available with [struts2 jquery plugin](http://code.google.com/p/struts2-jquery)

```
<sj:dialog 
    id="myeditdialog" 
    autoOpen="false" 
    modal="true" 
    title="Edit User"
/>

<s:url id="edit_user_url_1" action="edit"/><s:param name="id">1</s:param>
<sj:a 
    openDialog="myeditdialog"
    href="%{edit_user_url}"
>

<s:url id="edit_user_url_2" action="edit"/><s:param name="id">2</s:param>
<sj:a 
    openDialog="myeditdialog"
    href="%{edit_user_url_2}"
>
```